# Album with exclamation mark in Google Plus Photo

Tags: google-plus

One of my album has exclamation mark over the thumbnail as below,

[image: sample]

Any one has idea for the meaning of it? I know it should be related to some warning but it shows no details even I keep hover my cursor over the exclamation mark.